# Turn SUMIFS into SUMIF

Tags: excel, sumifs

I am trying to simplify a SUMIFS formula by using a list of criteria in a SUMIF function. However, my SUMIF formula only seems to consider the first criteria. What am I missing? Please see image and formulas below.

```
=SUMIFS(C1:C10,B1:B10,"<>ebay",B1:B10,"<>best buy",B1:B10,"<>amazon")
```

```
 =SUMIF(B2:B10,{"<>amazon","<>best buy","<>ebay"},C2:C10)
```

[image]

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: The logic of the both formulas is totally different. First is: Sum C if B<>"ebay" AND B<>"best buy" AND B<>"amazon". So exclude ebay, best by and amazon from the sum. Second - wrapped in `SUM` - is: Sum C if B<>"ebay" plus sum C if B<>"best buy" plus sum C if B<>"amazon". ???

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your SUMIF in a SUM function.

=SUM(SUMIF(B2:B10,{"<>amazon","<>best buy","<>ebay"},C2:C10))

This link should be helpful:
https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/11/12/excel-sumifs-sumif-multiple-criteria/#sumif-multiple-criteria

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `IF` combined with `SUM`:

```
=SUM(IF((B1:B10<>"ebay")+(B1:B10<>"best buy")+(B1:B10<>"amazon"),C1:C10,0))
```

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd> to enter this as an array formula.

Answer (score 0):

```
=SUM(IF((B1:B10<>"ebay")*(B1:B10<>"best buy")*(B1:B10<>"amazon"),C1:C10))
```

Press `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `ENTER` to enter this as an array formula.

Comment: This answer looks just like mine, but your rep is higher so you must have written it first.